# Add image in the WhatsApp share ( Jquery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, whatsapp

Here I am using jQuery to share text in WhatsApp. Now I want to share an image. Is it possible?

```
var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
```

Comment: I think it is not possible sharing images as attachments even you encode image content as a base64 string. However, you are able to share a image link instead. WhatsApp will display `og:image` for preview in chatroom.